# Is the step here valid this way?

Tags: complex-analysis

If we have,$$A=d[(\bar{\alpha}-\alpha)(dt+\lambda)]$$
where $\alpha$ is a complex function and $\lambda$ is a 1-form. t here represents the time coordinate.

If we want to calculate $d\star A=0$ where $\star$ is hodge star, we get if I did my calculations correctly $$\Delta[(\bar{\alpha}-\alpha)(dt+\lambda)]=0$$

From the product rule, we get $$(\bar{\alpha}-\alpha)\Delta (dt+\lambda)+ (dt+\lambda)\Delta (\bar{\alpha}-\alpha) +2 \Delta(\bar{\alpha}-\alpha)\Delta(dt+\lambda)=0$$
 **Does it mean here that each term must equal zero and thus since $(\bar{\alpha}-\alpha)$ can not be zero in the first term so $\Delta(dt+\lambda)=0$ thus killing with it the third term in the equation and only leaving the second term?**
That is simplifying the above equation, we get, $$(dt+\lambda)\Delta (\bar{\alpha}-\alpha)=0$$ thus leaving us with $$\Delta (\bar{\alpha}-\alpha)=0$$